# My Java program reaches 80% cpu usage after 20-30 min

Tags: java, database, web-crawler, cpu

I have a java program that crawls for some data on some sites and inserts it into  the database.

The Program keeps doing this :

1. Get the html
2. Extract the relevant data with some splits
3. Insert into to database

For the first 5-10 min it runs perfectly and very fast but after 20-30 min it becomes too slow and suddenly the program takes 80% cpu (in the beginning it takes something like 4%).

Do you know any reason why this might happen?

Comment: Don't know enough about Java to know if this is relevant, but have you remembered to close / dispose things after performing IO operations? (ie: retrieving HTML, inserting stuff to database, etc.)

Comment: You should use a profiler to work out where the CPU is being used. Without any specific code, there's no way we can tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @JonSkeet how can i use profiler?
I can't copy paste my code here because it's too long

Comment: This sound like resources problem. Did you close all your resources in finally statements? Did you start Threads, which are not finishing and keep going on and on?

Comment: Well have you done any research on how to use a profiler?

Comment: You can try fixed thread pool executor for restricting thread creation beyond some threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sound like resources problem. Did you close all your resources in finally statements? Did you start Threads, which are not finishing and keep going on and on?

Comment: I have threads that aren't finishing and keep going on. how this can be a problem? (after closing my program the cpu become normal again, they aren't keep running when the program stopped)

Comment: Every thread consumes CPU, if your start many threads and after they do work for you they did not end, they become zombie CPU consumers. You need to program such threads, that they end, when they finish the job. If you have ifinite loop inside a thread like while(true) or for(;;) and you don't break it, it will run forever (till the end of your program by killing it). Look in the debuger mode, you will see in stack trace all running Therads in the debuger view.

Comment: @ KrzysztofCichocki but my threads never finish their job. I want this program to work days without stop...

Comment: Ok, but maybe you keep running more, and more threads, and when the number of thread grows, your CPU usage also. You can run your app for weeks, of course, it is normal. But you need to keep track of your resources, clean them up and manage, because without that you will go into memory leaks, or even CPU leaks.

Comment: You have asked for hint, without your code it is very hard to tell what is heppening.

Comment: Ok you probably solve my problem. In my try catch i always called the program to run again when i get exception or error. my program in the start divide the work for 10 threads so that means when 1 thread get exception he got killed and new 10 thread are new to come. i try to delete it and i will update here if it solved. thanks